# Display message depending on capability outside loop

Tags: posts, php, author

I want to display a unique message on the post (single.php) page **outside the loop** on author box. I want the message to be different depending on the author's capabilities. So for instance, if the author can `manage_options` then echo `this is admin`, else if the author can `edit_others_posts` then echo `this is editor` and finally else `this is contributor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `global $authordata`:

Testing for roles:

```
global $authordata;    

if ( in_array( 'administrator', $authordata->roles ) )
{
   echo 'Hello Admin!';
}
elseif ( in_array( 'editor', $authordata->roles ) )
{
    // echo something else
}
```

Or testing for capabilities:

```
if ( ! empty ( $authordata->allcaps['manage_options'] ) )
{
   echo 'The author can manage options';
}
elseif ( ! empty ( $authordata->allcaps['edit_others_posts'] ) )
{
    // echo something else
}
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want 'current user', I want it to be post author.

Comment: if you please read my question again, it is for an author bio box outside the loop on post page.

Comment: @jack See my update.

Answer (score 0):

After the loop in single.php

```
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

place this:

```
<?php
if ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) )
{
echo 'This is the editor';
}
elseif ( current_user_can( 'contributer' ) )
{
echo 'This is contributor';
} ?>
```

Now under the post, it will say 'This is the editor' or 'this is the contributor' based on the capability of the user.

Comment: First, please explain your code instead of providing a _code-only_ answer. Second, this is not an answer to what was asked.